# Is there an official UK law that gives the spelling of each word?

Tags: united-kingdom

Is there an official UK law that gives the spelling of each word?

For example, in the Netherlands, there is a spelling law (Spellingswet), and they also publish the Green Booklet to make it accessible to the people.

I wonder if there is a similar thing for British English.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. English is not government-regulated. That's why the Oxford English Dictionary (arguably the most authoritative dictionary out there) uses different spellings than most of the UK does.

Comment: I see. Is there a section in the law of the united kingdom that says that English is not government-regulated? Or is it just based on 'it is not there'?

Comment: @wythagoras: It's just not there.

Comment: In fact, there's no UK law that even says English is the official language of the UK.... some of our laws are based very literally on the fact that "It just is" (see: de facto)

Comment: I use the Oxford English Dictionary on a daily basis, and it is utter nonsense to say that it uses different spellings to most of the UK. It is undoubtedly the most authoritative reference, in existence, on the English language  as it is spoken worldwide. But it maintains corpuses from all manner of varieties of spoken and written English. It provides spelling variants and will tell you when something is American, Indian, Australasian, South African etc. If you are interested in learning more about this I suggest the Stack Exchange, English Language and Users site.

Comment: @WS2 http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/132456?redirectedFrom=organize#eid -- Oxford spelling uses the -ize suffix, where British English generally uses -ise. The differences are not major, but they are there.

Comment: @cpast You are right, but that is the only example I can think of. However the *ize* suffix is used extensively in academic papers in Britain.

Comment: @JonStory You are undoubtedly right. But if you turned up at court expecting the proceedings to be heard in Japanese you might be disappointed.

Comment: Undoubtedly, I was just suggesting to wythagoras that attempting to find English laws relating to use of the English language is likely  waste of time considering there's no law even saying it is our official language, never mind regulating it.

Comment: @cpast According to [http://tinyurl.com/jg69j42](Google NGram viewer), the _ize_ suffix was almost twice as common in British English until at least 2008.

Comment: @Dan The British National Corpus says "-ise" is more common. I'm not so sure I trust NGrams on this; NGrams is books only, and leans towards academic books, while the BNC includes newspapers. Also, look at [this](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=organized+labour%2Corganized+labor%2C+organised+labour&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=18&smoothing=3), where NGrams is saying that British English commonly uses "organized labor" (the reason for this is that it includes some books by Americans published in the UK).

Comment: NGrams also tends to be *very* heavy on scientific work (and academic work in general), because its source material is often coming from university libraries. It doesn't include newspapers, which tend to be much more reflective of common use than academic works.

Comment: @cpast Fair enough, but it's also perfectly reasonable for the OED to have a bias towards those sorts of works (peer-reviewed journals and scholarly books rather than newspapers) in their definition of where "proper" English is to be found.